# как сделать в своем классе конструктор функции?

Tags: kotlin

у класса Button есть функция `.setOnClickListener{}`, где после нажатия на кнопку будет выполняться то, что написано в фигурных скобках.
как сделать подобное для своего класса?

Comment: И это как совсем не ООП ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не "конструктор функции", это просто передача лямбды как аргумента в метод.

На kotlin `.setOnClickListener{}` - это то же самое что `.setOnClickListener() {}` и то же самое что `.setOnClickListener({})`. Лямбда (то что в фигурных скобках) просто передается в метод как аргумент. Если она последний аргумент - она может выноситься из круглых скобок, если единственный аргумент - круглые скобки можно опустить (см. [Passing trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas))

Пример, то что передано в `doSomething` будет вызвано внутри этого метода:

```
class Test {
    fun doSomething(handler: () -> Unit) {
        handler.invoke()
    }
}


fun main() {
    val test = Test()

    test.doSomething({
        println("Hello 1")
    })

    test.doSomething() {
        println("Hello 2")
    }

    test.doSomething {
        println("Hello 3")
    }
}
```